# Free an Array of Linked Lists

Tags: c, free

So, I have having trouble freeing the memory I have allocated for my array of linked lists.

Here is my `typedef struct`:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int id;
    int degree;
    int distance;
    int status;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

Here is where I create the arrays

```
Node *graph = malloc( sizeof(Node) * N);
if (graph == NULL) {
    printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
    n = create_node(i);
    graph[i] = *(n);
}
Node *graph2 = malloc( sizeof(Node) * N);
if (graph2 == NULL) {
    printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
    n = create_node(i);
    graph2[i] = *(n);
}
```

Here is `create_node`:

```
Node* create_node(int id) {
    // Allocate memory for the structure
    Node *n = malloc( sizeof (Node) );
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->id = id; // set the value that identifies the node
    n->distance = INT_MAX; //we don't know teh source yet, so distance is infinity
    n->next = NULL;
    n->status = 0;
    return n; }
```

Here is the code where I try to free the arrays

```
for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
    free_node(&graph[i]);//<---here
    graph = NULL;
    free_node(&graph2[i]);
    graph2 = NULL;
}
```

And this is my `free_node` function:

```
int free_node(Node *n) {
    Node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    while (n != NULL) {//<---here
        tmp = n;
        n = n.next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault at the lines of code labeled above by "<---here" as a comment at the end of the line. It starts in my free_node function where it is called from freeing `graph[i]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You've shown most of the code we need.  You don't show the `create_node()` function, which would show whether you initialize the `next` member of the structures sensibly.  That is probably key to solving the problem.  The memory allocation in `free_node()` is very unexpected too.  In fact, it is generally a leak (assuming `n` is usually not null).  Use `Node *tmp = n;` inside the loop and remove the allocation.  That may not be relevant to the crash, but it is a real problem that also needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are trying to free a `struct` by sending the pointer of the `struct` but you are assigning a `NULL` value to those pointers after the first iteration, making them **danging pointers**.

**Check the following fix**:

```
for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
    free_node(graph + i);
    free_node(graph2 + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of linked lists (actually 2 arrays here) should be an array of pointers to the first node of each linked list. You created arrays of `Node` and then discarded the memory pointer, so you were unsuccessful in trying to free memory later.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N  10           // number of lists

typedef struct Node {
    int id;
    int degree;
    int distance;
    int status;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node **graph, **graph2;

Node* add_node(Node *root, int id) {
    // Add a node to the list with begins at root, return new root
    Node *n = malloc( sizeof (Node) );
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->id = id;
    n->degree = 0;
    n->distance = INT_MAX;
    n->status = 0;
    n->next = root;
    return n;
}

void free_list(Node *root) {
    // free the list which starts with root
    Node *tmp;
    while (root) {
        tmp = root->next;    
        free(root);
        root = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    Node *tmp;

    // create the arrays
    graph = malloc( sizeof(Node*) * N);
    if (graph == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    graph2 = malloc( sizeof(Node*) * N);
    if (graph2 == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
        graph[i] = NULL;
        graph2[i] = NULL;
    }

    // create one list
    for (i=0; i < 12; i++)
       graph[3] = add_node (graph[3], i);

    // check the list
    tmp = graph [3];
    while (tmp) {
        printf ("%d ", tmp->id);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    // free the linked lists
    for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
        free_list(graph[i]);
        graph[i] = NULL;    // added later
        free_list(graph2[i]);
        graph2[i] = NULL;   // added later
    }
    // free the arrays
    free (graph);
    free (graph2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to declare graph as an array of pointers if i did graph[i] = n?

Comment: I rewrote the answer.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention was that these linked lists in graph are of variable length. So I can't use the for loop code that you have commented //create one list. What I am creating is a graph in adjacency list representation to compute the diameter of the graph.

Comment: The `for` loop was just an example to show the list works. A linked list can be any length, subject to available memory. One way my solution differs from yours, is that there can be empty lists, indicated by a NULL pointer in your `graph` array, as opposed to an unused node.

Comment: I added 2 more lines to set the list pointers to NULL after the lists are freed, in case the program needs to re-use `graph` and `graph2`.